# Pinterest images not repinning: Sorry! Something went wrong on our end. Please try again

Tags: joomla, widget, pinterest, pinning

I added pinterest buttons on my website and pinning worked fine.
Recently users have tried to pin images, so they click on the button, a window with the image shows up, but when they select the board where they want to save the pin, they get an error: "Sorry! Something went wrong on our end. Please try again."
I have searched online for answers, and there are many others with the same issue.  These are a few solutions I've tried:
- clear cache
- remove robots.txt file
- recover original htaccess file (it's a joomla website)

I have also tried the Widget builder with several images from my site, but when I test it in the preview window, I get the same error. (I tried the preview button with images from other sites and it works).

Anybody else with this problem?

Comment: Is this still happening? Maybe it's a problem on their end. :)

Comment: Have you tried testing the URL on https://developers.pinterest.com/tools/url-debugger/?

Comment: Hi again, I tried everything and the problem went away for awhile. Now it's back, no matter what I do.  I tested it on a plain html page with one image and nothing else, and it didn't work.  I tested it again with an image from another site and it works.  For some reason my images are being blocked.
I tried the debugger but that's only for rich pins.   
I have tried contacting Pinterest support, but no answer :(

Answer (score 0):

We had the same issue and it was caused the the SSL certificate of the site.

We previously had Comodo SSL but I'm not sure why pinterest had issues with it.
I switched to use the free LetsEncrypt certificate and the issue is fixed.

I have tried to test the ssl certificate on this link:
https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html

I got the following results.

- Comodo SSL - B
- LetsEncrypt - A

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. 
After I fixed warnings by https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html, pinning works just fine.

I had an issue with invalid .ca-bundle file